# Measure Context Switch in JRuby

Tags: java, jruby

We running a multi-thread JRuby (9.0.5.0) application. And we are seeing some awfully long timing for our request to respond back(sometime). Like 4-5 sec, and sometimes even larger than this.. around 1-3 minute at a time when our AVG response time is around 90-100ms.

The issue happens for a very short time(at random) and behaves normally after the initial glitch.

We have traced the GC info but found nothing in it to reflect that GC pause would have resulted in such long response time.

My hypothesis has now been shifted to the time lost in Context switching.

So I'm here to understand whether?

Are there a ways to..

- Measure the Overall Context switch(the cumulative) timing for the parent process.
- Report an individual context switch timing for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

> My hypothesis has now been shifted to the time lost in Context switching.

would not go there - unless you have thousands of threads the JVM is fine tuned with (its very own) context switching. sounds like you're going down the wrong path here. instead you should try doing some profiling or get someone on board who has more JVM experience.